# Why does a Samba Share Printer Not Prompt For User and Password In windows 7 clients?

Tags: samba

I have installed Samba with CUPS on Ubuntu server and I shared a Canon ImageRunner 1133.

The printer works fine no problem but I want Windows clients to prompt for user and password when users click on the printer share.

Now even though I set `guest ok = no` under `[printers]` section the windows 7 client does not prompt for user, when I click the printer it says `no driver found`.

I installed the driver it prints without password please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sharing the printer through Samba or CUPS? I have made the mistake before of sharing it through CUPS before which does not ask for a user name or password. If you're adding the printer through Devices and Printers and then adding the printer by doing `http://ipaddress:631/printers/nameOfPrinter` chances are pretty good you've set up sharing in CUPS rather than Samba. You should also check the settings located at `localhost:631/admin` This will have check boxes, make sure you don't have the one labeled "Share printers connected to this system" enabled.